# Родственны ли слова "казнь" и "казна"?

Tags: этимология, лексика

Внезапно подумалось: "казнь" и "казна" - родственные слова или просто созвучные?

Comment: В чём родственность видится?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Слова не родственные.
**Казна** заимств. из тур. χaznä, крым.-тат. χazna -- то же, тат. χazinä. 
По поводу этимологии слова **казнь** единого мнения нет. Возможно, первоначально как "распоряжение"  от *казать* (Бернекер 1, 496 и сл.). Не менее вероятно родство с *каяться*. Но эти версии указывают на собственно славянское происхождение слова **казнь**.